# How do I return a single boolean from a set of booleans?

Tags: c#, boolean, return

Each item in `aList` returns either true or false. I am trying to return a boolean based on the following requirements:

If all the items in `aList` return true, I want `MethodDetails()` to return `true` as well.

But, if any of the elements inside `aList` returned false, I want each one of those elements to keep its return value, but have `MethodDetails()` to return false.

```
public class aClass
{
    bool returnType;
    private list aList;
    ArrayList tempList = new ArrayList();

    protected override object MethodDetails()
    {
        foreach (var element in aList)
        {
            MainMethod();
            tempList.Add(returnType);
        }

        //this is what I tried but it didn't work
        /*if (tempList.Contains(returnType))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return returnType;
        }*/
    }

    private bool MainMethod()
    {
        if (File.Exists(aFile)
        {
            if (int x != int y)
            {
                return false;
                returnType = false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
                returnType = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false
            returnType = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following linq query:

```
return !tempList.OfType<bool>().Any(x => !x);
```

Also, consider using `List<bool>` instead of `ArrayList`.

If you just want to verify if all files exist this is simplest:

```
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();    
return fileNames.All(File.Exists);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are setting returnType correctly. You are returning from the MainMethod before setting the returnType value. I think you MainMethod should look something like this

```
private bool MainMethod()
{
    if (File.Exists(aFile)
    {
        if (int x != int y)
        {
            returnType = false; // Changed
            return false;

        }
        else
        {
            returnType = true; // Changed
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        returnType = false; // Changed
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//you must add this below your foreach in MethodDetails()
foreach (var element in tempList)
    {
        if(element.Equals(false))
            return false;
    }

return true;
```

Hope this helps :)